# A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<java.util.UUID>, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have the following resource method:

```
  @POST
  @Path("{team_id}/users")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response addUsers(final @PathParam("team_id") UUID teamId, final List<UUID> userIds) {
        ...
  }
```

And the following test:

```
resource().path("teams").path(teamId).path("users")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, new JSONArray(Lists.newArrayList(UUID.fromString("123"), UUID.fromString("456"))));
```

But am getting an 'Unsupported Media Type' exception, and the message:

A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Comment: At first glance, looks like you're missing a @Consumes annotation that describes which media types are allowed for this method. Jersey then can't find where to go with the request of type "application/json" (which you set explicitly in your test).

Comment: Thanks, though still get same message after annotation with consumes JSON. @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace? Your problem might not only be the media type, but the 'userIds' parameter as well. Jersey has no information on how to fill it (and with what).